# Is there some way to rescale a slice of a canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas

My project includes a canvas element that is 800x2000. What I need to do is take a 200x2000 slice of the canvas and display it in the same 800x2000 location. What method or combination of methods might help me accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; use the 9-argument form of [`drawImage()`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage) to draw the slice of the canvas (i.e., the **s**ource) onto itself (i.e., the **d**estination) as follows:

```
function rescale(slice_start) {
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, slice_start, 0, slice_start + 200, 2000, 0, 0, 800, 2000)
}
```

Comment: `slice_start` should be between 0 and 600.